# What are the available functions to send notifications to a Facebook user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebooktoolkit

Currently I am using Codeplex's Facebook Developer Toolkit version 2 for my ASP.net Facebook application.  I would like to be able to send notifications to a user's Inbox or wall of the application and was wondering what are the available functions to do that?  If not in the API, then please provide example functions from the main Facebook library.  This will help immensely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a brief search I found an example of sending notifications using the toolkit:

> facebook.Components.FacebookService fs
>   = new facebook.Components.FacebookService();
>   fs.ApplicationKey =
>   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];
>   fs.Secret =
>   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"];
>   string sessionKey =
>   dict["facebook_session_key"];
>   fs.SessionKey = sessionKey; fs.uid =
>   long.Parse(member.FacebookId);
>   fs.notifications.send(member.FacebookId,
>   "notification message");

(from: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=49876)

After looking through the Codeplex source it's clear that this sends a user-to-user notification, and therefore requires an active user session of the sender.

Codeplex does not appear to support app-to-user notifications which do not require a session, but adding this feature would be trivial. Add a type variable to the send method and set it accordingly based on the API documentation here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.send

The source code for the notifications.send method in the Codeplex Developer Toolkit is here:
http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/28656#233852

Please keep in mind that the Codeplex developer toolkit source code has not been updated in over 3 months. This means that it does not support many new Facebook API features and changes. You may want to browse the client library wiki page to find a library that is more up to date: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Client_Libraries